# Where is $f$ analytic if $f(z)=\tan(z+i)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, roots

Let $f(z)=\tan(z+i)$. Where is $f$ analytic? 
 
 I know that the process of determining analyticity is to find the zeros of $f(z)$ and I also know that $\tan z$ has zeros at $z=\frac{\pi}2+n\pi$.  So would that mean $f(z)$ has zeros at $z=\frac{\pi}2+n\pi+i$ and so is analytic everywhere except at that zero? 
 
 UPDATE 
 So I realized the error of my thinking, and I think I might have it now. 
 $tanz=\frac{sinz}{cosz}$, therefore $tan(z+i)=\frac{sin(z+i)}{cos(z+i)}$. 
 $tanz$ doesn't exist when $cos(z+i)=0$ so that's what I need to solve for. 
 $$cos(z+i)=\frac{e^{i(z+i)}+e^{-i(z+i)}}2=0$$ 
 $$e^{i(z+i)}+e^{-i(z+i)}=0$$ 
 $$e^{iz-1}+e^{-iz+1}=0$$ 
 $$\frac{e^{iz}}e+\frac{e}{e^{iz}}=\frac{e^{2iz}+e^2}{e\cdot e^{iz}}= \frac{e^2(e^{iz}+1)}{e^{1+iz}}=0$$ 
 For the numerator: 
 $$e^2(e^{iz}+1)=0$$ 
 $$e^{iz}=-1$$ 
 $$z=\pi +2n\pi$$ 
 For the denominator: 
 $$e^{1+iz}$$ can never equal $0$. 
 So **$f$ is analytic everywhere except where $z=\pi +2n\pi$**. 
 Am I close?? And thanks for all your help!

Comment: It's zeroes of the "denominator", not the function itself. But it looks like you got that anyway, except you shifted them wrong.

Comment: $\cos z$ is zero at $z=\pi/2$ (for example), so $\cos(z+i)=0$ e.g. when $z+i=\pi/2,$ i.e., when $z=\pi/2-i.$

Comment: Actually, $\tan z$ does not have zeros at $z=\pi/2+n\pi,$ it has poles at $z=\pi/2+n\pi.$ Moreover, the solution of $z+i=\pi/2+n\pi$ is $z=\pi/2+n\pi-i,$ not $z=\pi/2+n\pi+i.$

Answer (score 0):

Sine  and cosine functions are entire functions. Hence tan is Holomorphic everywhere except at the zeros of Cosine. Namely your function is Holomorphic everywhere except at the points where  one has

$$\cos(z+i)=0\Longleftrightarrow z=\frac{\pi}2+n\pi-i
$$

Thus $\tan(z+i)$ is Holomorphic on $\Bbb C\setminus \{z=\frac{\pi}2+n\pi-i : n\in \Bbb Z\}$